# Debug .hex file with STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I am quiet new to STM32 developement.

I made a custom .hex file, which corresponds to my binary file with a CRC at a given address. To achieve this, I followed [this instructions](https://github.com/ethanhuanginst/STM32CubeIDE-Workshop-2019/tree/master/hands-on/06_F746-DISCO-CRC).

Right now, I am stuck at step 11, where the author tells STM32CubeIDE to debug current project with its custom .hex file instead of standard .elf file.

My problem is that this instructions are quiet old and IDE's UI is different now. How can I achieve this step with latest STM32CubeIDE version ? (1.6.1 at time of writing)

Thanks.

Comment: Generally you need programm patched hex file and run debug without reprogramming flash memory of your controller. It's can be achived manually or with some IDE features which are significatly depend on IDE and it version. Basically, as standard, each IDE shoul provide ability to call some external command after each compile, so you can patch and reprogramm your controller using this IDE feature. Or you can write script to do this extrenally to save lifetime of internal flash. May be your IDE can call some command before start debug - this will be optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

1. Create HEX
2. Manually flash it
3. Start debugging the normal way. Simply do not let openOCD or ST-LinkGDBServer to flash the chip.
4. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But how can I not let openOCD or ST-Link flash the chip ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but what worked for me (my IDE version is 1.11.0):

[image: Debug configuration page]

The first line is the path to the `hex` file which will be loaded in the flash memory.
The second one is the path to the `elf` file (that is used to create the `.hex` file loaded in memory) from which symbols only are loaded.

Answer (score -1):

I have got the same problem, and my solution is to use stm32cubeProgrammer. It can't show the debug information, so I use usart to show the CRC result.